# Installing Mongodb "no section headers." Error

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos6, yum

I am trying to install mongodb on Centos 6.6. I am following the steps here: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-6/

I have added the following (where it states on the tutorial):

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

As you can see here:

[image]

However, when I try and install I get the following error

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

My file listing for `/etc/yum.repos.d` is;

```
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 26 13:12 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 66 root root 4.0K Jun 24 14:19 ..
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Oct 23 2014 CentOS-Base.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 647 Oct 23 2014 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 289 Oct 23 2014 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 630 Oct 23 2014 CentOS-Media.repo
8.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.3K Oct 23 2014 CentOS-Vault.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Jul 3 2015 city-fan.org.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 191 Jun 26 12:56 mongodb-org-3.2.repo
12K -rw------- 1 root root 12K Jun 26 12:53 .mongodb-org-3.2.repo.swp
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200 Jun 26 13:12 mongodb-org-3.4.repo
12K -rw------- 1 root root 12K Jun 26 12:55 .mongodb-org.repo.swp
12K -rw------- 1 root root 12K Jun 24 14:16 .mongodb.repo.swp
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 472 Apr 26 2016 nodesource-el.repo
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219 Dec 18 2013 vz.repo
```

Comment: Answer updated for when you edit this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message it would appear that at least one of your `.repo` files is corrupt.

The file `mongodb-org-3.2.repo` has an errant `\n` on line 2 But looking at your file listing it would appear you have several files, some of which are corrupted (hence the `.swp` files left behind)

You should do a full file listing with `ls -lash /etc/yum.repos.d` and delete all the files with 'mongo' in the name.

Then create a new file named `mongodb.repo` and add the following to it;

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

Then run `yum install mongodb-org`

Comment: Its doing the same thing :(

Comment: Sorry was away yesterday, I'm very unfamiliar with a lot of these commands and linux stuff (so apologies). If you don't mind that would be great

Comment: hi mate sure, sorry for the delay

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147988/room-for-user3788685-and-bcltd

Answer (score 0):

I think the param in [mongodb] is not enough and is a lack of header information. you should specify the version as well.

for example for MongoDB v2.0, il should look like:

```
[mongodb-org-2.0]
name=...ect
```

regards